# PostgreSQL связь один ко многим и INSERT

Tags: postgresql

Начал изучать pgsql и столкнулся с глупейшей ситуацией, но не знаю как ее решить.
Есть 2 таблицы: пользователи и задачи. Между ними установлена связь один ко многим по полю логина таблицы пользователей - у всех задач должен быть пользователь. Как правильно сформировать запрос на добавление новой записи в таблицу задач?

Создавал таблицы вот так:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    login varchar(30) PRIMARY KEY,
    pass VARCHAR(32)
    );

CREATE TABLE tasks (
    num integer PRIMARY KEY,
    login VARCHAR(30) REFERENCES users (login),
    body text
    );
```

Не откажусь от совета, как это правило было бы сделать, если мой вариант совсем неверен.
При создании записи в таблицу таск я точно буду знать логин. При желании могу вытащить ID - все равно перед запросом к таблицу таск будет запрос в таблицу юзерс для проверки валидности логин\пароля

Comment: Для формирования запроса необходимо знать имена полей и их тип, Добавте - `create table ...`.

Comment: Это зависит от того, какая информация доступна в момент добавления задачи. Если вам уже откуда то известен логин пользователя (почему только не id) то его и пишите. А если что до другое то можно `insert into ... select`'ом выбрать логин и записать его одновременно

Comment: добавил код создания

Comment: Если вам уже известен логин, то какие сложности с вставкой задачи ? `insert into tasks(num,login,body) values(1,'login','aaa')` Кстати, номера задач как формируются, каким нибудь секвенсом ?

Comment: Да, заработало, спасибо! Пробовал до этого без явного указания порядка полей - не срабатывало.. Номер планируется вычислять на стороне бэкенда - брать все числа из колонки, вычислять максимальное и делать инкримент. Как сделать это легко и доступно на постгресе не нашел, а для тестового приложения экспериментировать с бд можно будет позже